# Add cascade delete for all nested child in hierarchy chain

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, design-patterns, entity-framework-core

I would like to get the following behavior, when deleting an object from a parent level of first level, all entities "child" were deleted automatically, say I have a Library class that has a list "areas", each area has a list of "corridors", and each corridor has a "ranks" list, each rank has a list of books. Did you understand that the level is going down?

**Schematic model:**

```
Library 
-----> Area
----------> Corridors
---------------> Ranks
--------------------> Book
```

**Classes:**

```
class Library {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Area> Areas {get;set;}
}

class Area {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Library Library {get;set;}
    public List<Corridor> Corridors {get;set;}
}

class Corridor {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Area Area {get;set;}
    public List<Rank> Ranks {get;set;}
}

class Rank {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Corridor Corridor {get;set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get;set;}
}

class Book {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Rank Rank {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I wish that when I erased Library, I would erase the children that were needed within the chain, cascade. I can do this with the following code, I made all my classes inherit from a common class that I called "Registry", and that all of them had a common property called "Library", and I configured it as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(Registry).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(prop =>
    {
        modelBuilder
        .Entity(prop.Name)
        .HasOne(typeof(Library), "Library")
        .WithMany()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    });
```

I tested with a 20 classes and ran, in the created migration, all 20 entities, have an FK pointing to **Library**, called **"LibraryId"** and with the property, **"onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade"**, but I have a structure with 650 classes, it is completely impracticable to be inheriting all of them from the **Registry** class, I think there should be a simpler and more efficient way, but I do not know how to do it ...

Comment: Why don't you simply enable the standard cascade delete for all relationships? i.e. `Library` will delete related `Areas`, they will delete related `Corridors` etc. It's a pretty standard database design, no need of redundant FK and multiple cascade paths.

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

For required relationships (non-nullable foreign key) it is not possible to save a null foreign key value, so cascade delete behavior is by default.

You can simply create hierarchy:

```
class Parent {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

class Child {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}

    public Guid ParentId {get;set;}
    public Parent Parent {get;set;}
}
```

And Ef core knows that children should be deleted with Parent because ParentId is Required. Read [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
class Library {
public int Id {get;set;}
public List<Area> Areas {get;set;}
}

class Area {
public int Id {get;set;}
public Library Library {get;set;}
public int LibraryId {get;set;}
public List<Corridor> Corridors {get;set;}
}

class Corridor {
public int Id {get;set;}
public Area Area {get;set;}
public int AreaId {get;set;}
public List<Rank> Ranks {get;set;}
}

class Rank {
public int Id {get;set;}
public Corridor Corridor {get;set;}
public int CorridorId {get;set;}
public List<Book> Books {get;set;}
}

class Book {
public int Id {get;set;}
public Rank Rank {get;set;}
public int RankId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Adding the RankId to the book class cause EF to use ondelete:cascade for Book and Rank. This goes for the other classes